# Azure Data Factory, BlobEventsTrigger: configure blob path with scheduledTime value which is dynamic content

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an Azure Data Factory pipeline with two triggers:

- [schedule trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-schedule-trigger?tabs=data-factory)
- [blob event trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger)

I would like for blob event trigger to wait for a marker file in storage account under dynamic path e.g.:

```
landing/some_data_source/some_dataset/@{formatDateTime(@trigger().scheduledTime, 'yyyyMMdd')}/_SUCCESS
```

Refering to `@trigger().scheduledTime` doesn't work.

How to pass `scheduleTime` parameter value from `schedule trigger` to `blob event trigger` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to **edit** blob event trigger fields **Blob path begins** with or **Blob path ends with** - using the **scheduleTime** from the scheduleTrigger!

Unfortunately, as we can confirm from the official MS doc [Create a trigger that runs a pipeline in response to a storage event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-create-event-trigger?tabs=data-factory#:%7E:text=Note%20that%20Blob%20path%20begins%20with%20and%20ends%20with%20are%20the%20only%20pattern%20matching%20allowed%20in%20Storage%20Event%20Trigger.%20Other%20types%20of%20wildcard%20matching%20aren%27t%20supported%20for%20the%20trigger%20type.)

> Blob path begins with and ends with are the only pattern matching
> allowed in Storage Event Trigger. Other types of **wildcard matching
> aren't supported** for the trigger type.

It takes the literal values.

**This does not work:**
[image]

[image]

**Only if you have a file names as same ! Unlikely**

[image]
[image]

Also, **this dosen't**

[image]

But, **this would**

[image]

**Workaround:**

As discussed with @[marknorkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3424394/marknorkin) earlier, since this is not available out-of-the-box in BlobEventTrigger, we can try use Until activity composed from GetMetadata+Wait activities, where in GetMetadata will check for dynamic path existence.